# C Programming Error (collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/COsH8.png
Hi everyone. I am new programmer.
As seen in the photo. I have got this error when C programming with Visual Studio Code .
I have added C/C++ and Code Runner. gcc to system

Can anyone who knows it help me ?

What did i do wrong or miss?

Comment: Like the error says, the compiler cannot find certain libraries. Make sure you installed your compiler correctly and that the necessary locations are added to your PATH.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: how are you invoking build and run? What action are you using? What related extensions do you have installed for VS Code?